# Laravel 5 - Many to Many relationship with field

Tags: many-to-many, eloquent, laravel-5

I have this scenario:
Students [
 id
 name 
 ....
]

Topics [
  id
  name
  ....
]

Topics_got [
   student_id
   topic_id
   vote
]

I known how to model it in Laravel 5 but I don't know how to insert new entries in Topics_got or retrieve data for example for 'vote'.
How can I make it?

Comment: Can you try this. $topic->students()->attach($id_student, ['vote' => $value]); ?

Comment: Yes, it works in creation of a pivot entry but what about a update?

Comment: And about getting the value?

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the pivot table (Topics_got) in order to get or update the value of 'vote'.

Following ChainLists comment, you can do it like this:

**Attaching a student to a topic**

```php
$topic->students()->attach($student_id, ['vote' => $value]);
```

**Getting the value of vote**

```php
// For a single student
$vote = $topic->students()->first()->pivot->vote; // Replace first() with your custom query

// Looping over all students
foreach($topic->students()->get() as $student)
{
    echo $student->pivot->vote;
}
```

**Updating the value of vote**

```php
$student = $topic->students()->first();
$student->pivot->vote = $newValue;
$student->pivot->save();
```

Comment: I did this: App\Student::find(3)->topics()->first()->pivot->vote, result was 'null' even though 3 is a reference of student in pivot and vote exists on database.

Comment: Maybe I have to do a sort of model of pivot table? (In the example Topics_got)

Comment: I can set and update but I can't read the value from database